# collections deque constructor

Tags: python, collections, deque

Can you explain the this constructor of deque:

```
import collections
buff = collections.deque([], 100)
```

I saw it's documentation but couldn't find this form being used anywhere.

Comment: What about the documentation is unclear?

Comment: As you've found the documentation, focus on what *maxlen* argument does. It is very well explained. There's also an example of what you're after in the [deque recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-recipes). Look at the *tail* function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> class collections.deque([iterable[, maxlen]])
>
> Returns a new deque object initialized left-to-right (using append())
>   with data from iterable. If iterable is not specified, the new deque
>   is empty.

In your example , `buff = collections.deque([], 100)`,

creates a new empty deque object `buff`, specified by the first argument, with maxlen 100. It means the deque object is bounded to a maximum length of 100.

Here is the [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to the documentation, it's explained nicely and pretty clear.